# Inserting Section Break Odd Page does not correctly insert a blank page in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2007

I have been working on a document in Word 2007 in which the new sections are supposed to start on odd pages. Initially, when I would place the cursor in the page immediately preceding my desired new section and then select `Page Layout` -> `Breaks`-> `Odd Page`  from the Ribbon (Alternatively `Alt,p,b,d`), a blank page would be inserted if necessary for the new section to start on an odd page. However, currently when I attempt this, it simply starts the new section on the following page, resulting in a section incorrectly starting on an even page. How can I correct this? Is there a way to find out if some underlying formatting is preventing it?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your actual page numbers.  When using the Break on Odd Page option, it does not show the even page it skips unless it has data.  I believe this is to make it easier for you to work on the document and not have to constantly scroll past empty pages.  However, when printing the document it does include the blank page (completely blank, even without the page number).